# Weird files appearing in waterfall report of WebPagetest.org

Tags: url, page-speed

I am using `webpagetest.org` to test my site's speed. I've noticed in the Waterfall View that there are files loading on my site which do not physically exist on the server, even though the URLs point to the root folder of my site.

For example:

```
http://www.offers.example.com/favicon.ico

http://www.offers.example.com/cdn-cgi/pe/bag2?r[]=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.offers.example.com%2Fwp-includes%2Fjs%2Fwp-emoji-release.min.js%3Fver%3D4.6.1
```

How is this possible?

Comment: Can you edit the question to include example URLs (using `example.com` as the domain)?

Comment: done. Can u check it out?

Comment: Could you include a screenshot of this waterfall view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The favicon request is the browser that WebPagetest uses requesting the favicon to show on the tab or elsewhere. Regardless of whether you actually have a favicon, the request will still be made because you might have a favicon which should be shown to the user if it was a real user accessing your website.

‘/cdn-cgi/pe/bag2’ is [Cloudflare's Rocket Loader](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200168056-What-does-Rocket-Loader-do-), which combines multiple ‘script src’ into one asynchronous request which returns all the JavaScript from all the individual requests in one go, amongst other things. The query parameter ‘r’ lists the URLs to the scripts that your page requests.